# orderBy is not working in Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am using the below query. **orderBy** is not working in below query. This query is working in localhost but it is not working in Online Server.

```
return DB::table('reports')
        ->leftJoin('sources', 'reports.report_source_id', '=', 'sources.id')
        ->select('*')
        ->orderBy('report_id', 'desc')
        ->take(10)
        ->get();
```

Comment: Could there be some kind of difference between the two databases - like collation or something that is causing the one to not work? When you say it is not working is the query running but not ordering or are there perhaps any error messages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting an alias for each table and then using the required alias on the orderBy

If there is a `report_id` in both tables it will not know which one to use and is probably throwing an error if you look for it.

```
return DB::table('reports as r')
    ->leftJoin('sources as s', 'r.report_source_id', '=', 's.id')
    ->select('*')
    ->orderBy('r.report_id', 'desc')
    ->take(10)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this..
use "reports.report_id";

```
return DB::table('reports')
        ->leftJoin('sources', 'reports.report_source_id', '=', 'sources.id')
        ->select('*')
        ->orderBy('reports.report_id', 'desc')
        ->take(10)
        ->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use reports.report_id like

```
return DB::table('reports')
        ->leftJoin('sources', 'reports.report_source_id', '=', 'sources.id')
        ->select('*')
        ->orderBy('reports.report_id', 'desc')
        ->take(10)
        ->get();
```

Comment: But you still use `->orderBy('report_id', 'desc')` instead of `->orderBy('reports.report_id', 'desc')`