# Sorting categories in page of the News & Newsletter component. OctoberCms

Tags: octobercms

Trying to sort categories in descending order of the News & Newsletter component, through a query in the database using `function onStart()`.
But sorting doesn't work

```
[newsCategories]
noPostsMessage = "Empty"
categoryPage = "newcategory"
==
function onStart()
{
$this['categories'] = Db::table('indikator_news_categories')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->get();
}
==
    {% for category in categories  %}
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ category.url }}">{{ category.name }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

By doing a little research I found this.

[orderBy is not working in Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31608034/orderby-is-not-working-in-laravel-5)

So try this:

```
$this['categories'] = Db::table('indikator_news_categories as categories')
    ->orderBy('categories.created_at', 'desc')
    ->get();
```